# Older than 10 months - jpql mysql

Tags: mysql, jpql

this is a sql query (MySQL), which finds employees that have worked longer than 10 months:

```
SELECT * FROM employeeinproject WHERE startDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MONTH);
```

How to transform this query to jpql query?

Comment: INTERVAL is not accepted in jpql, so I've tried BETWEEN keyword but it's difficult to implement business logic

Comment: Please read the guide how to ask a question here.http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve